# How does one mount a MS CIFS share in SmartOS?

Tags: cifs, illumos

How does one mount a Microsoft CIFS share in SmartOS?

Answer (score 1):

SmartOS is essentially [Illumos](http://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/illumos+Home) so if you know how to mount a CIFS share in Illumos, you can do it in SmartOS. Try `mount -F smbfs` and of course, the beloved `man mount` for more specific information.